# I do not understand how 世間 works with 一般 in this sentence

Tags: words, usage

I came across this sentence - **彼は世間一般の学生とは違っている**

I also read the meaning of the various kanji used here. If I'm not mistaken, 一般の学生 already means **ordinary students** or **average students**. But how does 世間 work in this sentence?

Another sentence I came across was similar to this one but did not use 世間. Here's that sentence - **彼女は一般の先生と比べればよい先生だ**.

So, I do not understand what the nuance is. Why is 世間 used in the first sentence? If I'm mistaken about something, please correct me.

Comment: 世間一般 appears to be a word/expression in its own right: https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%96%E9%96%93%E4%B8%80%E8%88%AC

Comment: @user3856370 Thank you :) Can I trouble you to also explain where would I use this word/expression? As I mentioned in my question, the second sentence doesn't use this but the first sentence does. How do I decide when and where to use it?

Comment: Afraid that's beyond my skill level. Best wait for someone else to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

一般 is *general* as opposed to *special*, and can also be a translation of *ordinary, average* (in the sense of non-special). 世間 originally meant *secular world* (as opposed to the world of Buddhist monks), and 世間一般 can be translated as *worldly, ordinary, average*.

A short answer is, in the sense of *average, ordinary*, you can most probably use always 一般 without changing the meaning (much).

Differences:

一般 can be attached to other nouns without の, 世間一般 can't. 一般[人]{じん}、一般の[人]{ひと}, 世間一般の[人]{ひと} are fine, but not 世間一般人.

世間一般 sounds more collective. Since both of your examples refer to a group of ordinary students/teachers, I don't see much difference 一般の学生/世間一般の学生 or 一般の先生/世間一般の先生. But

- その芸能人は一般の人と結婚した The TV celebrity married a person who is not in the show business.

Here 世間一般の人 wouldn't fit because it refers to a single person.